# Find min and max for $f(x)=x^2*(35-x)^5$. We may use calculus.

Tags: derivatives

I have got the following function:
$f(x)=x^2(35-x)^5$

I need to find the points that
$$f'(x)=0$$ in order to find extrema points, but
I cannot  find the derivative  due to exponents!

**Problem:**
I broke $(35-x)^5$ via binomial expansion ,but I think the approach was of no use..I have got higher order of polynomial expression .I dont know how to solve

So how should I approach in order to find its extrema using its derivative  point in the least costly way??

Thank You

Comment: ??Yes ,Go ahead..

Comment: It is not difficult to find the roots of the derivative, they should be 35, 0 and 10....

Comment: make some factorisation first

Comment: Just use product rule. Expanding the term manually and derivating will make it hard to factorise.

Comment: You're probably confusing product rule with chain rule (where order matters).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: 
$$
\begin{align}
(f\circ g)'(x) = f(g(x))' &= f'(g(x))\, g'(x) \\
f(x) &= x^5 \\
g(x) &= 35-x
\end{align}
$$
Hint: 
$$
(f g)'(x) = f'(x) g(x)+f(x)g'(x)
$$
Hint: 
$$
f'(x) = 7x(10-x)(35-x)^4
$$

Comment: ok Fine i derived the $(35-x)^5$  using above..But we got $x^2*(35-x)^5$ then which function should be choosen as first function here..I got LIATE rule to do which prevent me from moving foreward..I am confuse to choose ,as they both are algeberic functions

Comment: You might review your rules for taking a derivative.

Comment: But what about it...the first function...i mean if i got like $ sin^2\theta*(35-x)^2$then i wont ask such question..

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{dy}{dx}$=$(-1)x^{2}(5(35-x)^{4})+((35-x)^{5})(2x)$

=$(35-x)^{4}(-5x^{2}+70x-2x^{2})$

$(35-x)^{4}=0$  or $(-7x^{2}+70x)=0$

$ x=0, x=10, x=35 $

Should be easy solve from here hope this helps.

Comment: So you choosed $x^2$ as first function and derivied the equation

Comment: I used the product rule. let u=$x^{2}$ and v=$(35-x)^{5}$

Comment: Then $f'(x)$=u$\frac{dv}{dx}$+v$\frac{du}{dx}$ where the chain rule was applied to differentiate v

Comment: how did you assumed the first function and second function to apply product rule??I mean both of them are algeberic function

Comment: when you have a function in the form f(x)=u(x).v(x) you can apply product rule and u v can be in any order. Not being rude but you should familarise yourself with basic calculus before attempting to find max/mins of tougher functions.

Answer (score 0):

No need for calculus: $p(x)=x^2(35-x)^5$ has a double root at $x=0$ and a quintuple root at $x=35$; these points are clearly stationary points. There is no stationary point outside the interval $[0,35]$ since $p(x)$ is monotonic for $x>35$ or $x<0$. In the interval $[0,35]$ there is a unique maximum for $p(x)\geq 0$: by the AM-GM inequality

$$\begin{eqnarray*} x^2(35-x)^5 &=& \frac{4}{25}\left[\left(\tfrac{5}{2}x\right)\left(\tfrac{5}{2}x\right)(35-x)(35-x)(35-x)(35-x)(35-x)\right]\\&\color{red}{\leq}&\frac{4}{25}\left[\frac{2\cdot\left(\tfrac{5}{2}x\right)+5\cdot(35-x)}{7}\right]^5=\frac{4}{25}\left[25\right]^5 = 4\cdot 5^8 = 1562500\end{eqnarray*}$$
and $\color{red}{\leq }$ holds as $\color{red}{=}$ iff $\frac{5}{2}x=35-x$, i.e. iff $x=10$.

Comment: I can't get with AM-GM inequilaty

Comment: @ShivanshuRaj: what can't you get?

Comment: and how you can say that $p(x)$ is  monotonic without knowing its derivative?

Comment: Am-GM is sounds new are you  talking about Arthemetic mean or geometric mean??

Comment: @ShivanshuRaj: the product of two positive and increasing functions is positive and increasing, you do not need derivatives to be able to state it.  AM-GM is the standard name of the inequality between the arithmetic mean and the geometric mean.